# How to handle NoSuchElementException and NullPointerException in stream java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I got an issue to handle `NoSuchElementException` and `NullPointerEception`.

I tried to handle `NoSuchElementException` error from this code:

```
public Item shop(ItemShopParam itemShopParam) {
    String orderNumber = itemShopParam.getOrderNumber();
    Shipment shipment = shipmentService.findByNumber(orderNumber);

    Item item = findBySku(shipment.getId(), itemShopParam.getItemSku());
    Job job = item.getShipment().getJobs().stream().filter(j -> j.getType().equals(Job.Type.RANGER)).findFirst().get();
    checkJobState(job);

  private void checkJobState(Job job) {
    if (job.getState() == Job.State.INITIAL)
        throw new JobNotStartedException();
    if (job.getState() == Job.State.FINISHED)
        throw new JobAlreadyFinishedException();
}
```

by replace `get()` with `Optional().orElse(null)`. But, it returned another error exception `NullPointerException`. I know why this happened because `checkJobState` check `null` value of `job`.

The enum state:

```
public enum State {
    INITIAL(0),
    STARTED(1),
    LAST_ITEM_PICKED(2),
    FINALIZING(3),
    ACCEPTED(4),
    DELIVERING(5),
    FOUND_ADDRESS(6),
    FINISHED(7),
    FAILED(8);
```

What is the best practice to avoid `NoSuchElementException` without return `NullPointerException`?

Comment: This is all about your filter. Does `j -> j.getType().equals(Job.Type.RANGER)` match any element? If this filter is OK, then you just need to handle nulls in `checkJobState`: `if (job == null) throw new NoRangerJobException();`

Comment: If there is no results your `job` will be null and function invocation will throw `NullPointerException`, you can use `map()` function after `findFirst()` connected with `orElseThrow()` to handle case when job will be available and throw exception if won't be found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Optional.isPresent()` check:

```
Optional<Job> maybeJob = item.getShipment().getJobs().stream().filter(j -> j.getType().equals(Job.Type.RANGER)).findFirst();
if(maybeJob.isPresent()) {
    checkJobState(job);
}
```

or even better an `ifPresent()`:

```
Optional<Job> maybeJob = item.getShipment().getJobs().stream().filter(j -> j.getType().equals(Job.Type.RANGER)).findFirst().ifPresent(job -> checkJobState(job));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the instructions to get the job from itemShopParam in a java Function, in this way  you can  easy test it.
Then use try catch to get any unexpected behaviour and specialise it in your exception inside a catch block.
The exception fired could be checked, if extends Throwable or Runtime if you wants manage it optionally.

```
//FUNCTION CLASS
 class FromItemShopParamToJob implements Function<ItemShopParam,Item> 
 {

     @Override
     public Item apply(ItemShopParam itemShopParam) {

         Item i=new Item();
            //instructions to get job
         return  i;
     }
 }

 class FromItemToJob implements Function<Item,Job> {

    @Override
    public Job apply(Item item) {

        Job j=new Job();
        //instructions to get job
        return  j;
    }
}
 //YOUR EXCEPTION CLASS
 public class JobNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{


    public JobNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

 //YOUR METHOD
 public void getJobFromItemShop(ItemShopParam param){



try {

    Item item = new FromItemShopParamToJob().apply(param);

     Job j=new FromItemToJob().apply(item);

} catch (Exception e){

    System.out.print(e);

    throw new JobNotFoundException(e.toString());


}

}
```